# Como crear un secuencial por fecha actual

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando  un secuencial  el cual  este conformado por la fecha actual y un dígito incrementable,
por ejemplo

```
20190226_001
20190226_002
20190226_003 ...
20190227_001
20190227_002 ...
```

pero aun no logro hacer que funcione correctamente .

```
select  (concat(date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d'), LPAD((coalesce((MAX(substr(i_ticket,10,12 ))),0))+1 ,4,'_00'  ))) AS i_ticket
 from   ticket_support
WHERE i_ticket like ('20190227%') and  d_request= date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podría ser algo así:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'),'_',LPAD( @a:=@a+1,4,'0') ) AS i_ticket
  FROM ticket_support
 WHERE i_ticket like ('20190227%') 
   AND d_request = DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y%m%d')
```

Lo que se hace aquí es ayudarse de una [*variable de usuario*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), que se le incrementa en cada iteración, para ser usada como contador.

> #### 9.4 User-Defined Variables
>
> You can store a value in a user-defined variable in one statement and
>   refer to it later in another statement. This enables you to pass
>   values from one statement to another.
>
> User variables are written as @var_name, where the variable name
>   var_name consists of alphanumeric characters, ., _, and $. A user
>   variable name can contain other characters if you quote it as a string
>   or identifier (for example, @'my-var', @"my-var", or @`my-var`).
>
> User-defined variables are session specific. A user variable defined
>   by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. (Exception: A
>   user with access to the Performance Schema user_variables_by_thread
>   table can see all user variables for all sessions.) All variables for
>   a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits.
>
> User variable names are not case-sensitive. Names have a maximum
>   length of 64 characters.
>
> **Fuente:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

---

> **ATENCIÓN**
>
> No se reiniciará el contador si en vez de `now()` usas un campo fecha y este varía.

Answer (score 0):

Hola muchas gracias por la ayuda, en efecto  no se reiniciaba porque tenia  una columna de mas en el filtro where,  la solucion final  para mi fue:

select  (concat(date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d'), LPAD((coalesce((MAX(substr(i_ticket,10,12 ))),0))+1 ,4,'_00'  ))) AS i_ticket
 from   ticket_support
WHERE i_ticket like date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d%');

Gracias!